# Strings from input are never equal?

Tags: java, string, equality, string-comparison

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

public class Michal {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        reply();

    }
    public static void reply() {
        Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
        String name=input.nextLine();


        if(name=="john"){  
            System.out.println("bear!");
        }else if(name=="mary")
        {
             System.out.println("lovely lady!");
        }else{
            System.out.println("I don't know that person.");
        }
        System.out.println(name);
        input.close();
    }

}
```

I consider myself still a beginner to Java ,so please don't be harsh in your answers. I was trying to create a program that returns an answer every time it gets a certain input , however it seems to return "I don't know that person" all the time.

Comment: Do not use `==` for comparing string. Use `name.equals("john")` instead.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java

Comment: Very useful read: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/193638/why-didnt-operator-string-value-comparison-make-it-to-java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> if(name=="john")
> ```

is not the right way to compare strings. Use `equals()` instead:

```
if(name.equals("john")){  
        System.out.println("bear!");
} else if(name.equals("mary")){
```

Comment: @MichalManugiewicz No problem, click the checkmark to the left of my answer if it helped.